# Setting Up Generic View class for Flask

Tags: python, model-view-controller, flask

I am setting up an application using Flask based on a tutorial I found on the web. The problem I am having is so far it seems like I will have to write a lot of code for each view/route that I want to make so I am trying to devise a better system but I think I dug myself into a hole where I wrote too much code before really testing each step and since im not familiar with the framework im kindof lost.

so what I want is a base view class that will extract away some boilerplate stuff. Here is my attempt so far.

```
import jinja2
from jinja2 import Environment as Jinja2Environment
from webassets import Environment as AssetsEnvironment
from webassets.loaders import YAMLLoader
from webassets.ext.jinja2 import AssetsExtension
from flask import render_template
from app import app

class BaseView(object):

    def __init__(self):
        "init"

    def get_jinja_env(self):
        jinja_env = Jinja2Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates/'), extensions=[AssetsExtension])

        return jinja_env

    def get_asset_env(self):
        asset_loader = webassets.YAMLLoader('conf/assets.yml')
        asset_env = asset_loader.load_environment()
        bundles = asset_loader.load_bundles()
        [asset_env.register(name, bundle) for name, bundle in bundles.iteritems()]

        return asset_env

    def render_tmpl(self, tmpl_file, **context):
        "Renders Jinja Template"
        jinja_env = self.get_jinja_env
        jinja_env.assets_environment = self.get_asset_env

        template = jinja_env.get_template(tmpl_file)
        return template.render(context)
```

Class that attempts to inherit from BaseView

```
from app.BaseView import BaseView
from app import app

class HelloView(BaseView):

    @app.route('/')
    def respond(self):
        self.render_tmpl('hello.html')
```

My reasoning behind this is later I intend to extend some Jinja functionality such as caching and have some data be available for every view and template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the [View classes](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/) included in flask already.

As they are very well explained there is not much I could explain here. Just read through the docs and I think you will see, what you will have to do (the flask docs are awesome.)

If you want to cache you also might want to have a look at [Flask-Cache](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Cache/).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite answer your question entirely, but I thought it was worth mentioning anyway.

You can 'export' variables into the Jinja environment globals:

```
app.jinja_env.globals['data'] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

Once you've done this, all templates have access to the `data` variable and can operate on it as if it were passed in via `kargs`. You don't really need to go to the trouble of creating a whole new view class; you can just process it once and then make it available everywhere. It's handy for sidebars and login statuses and whatnot.